# Blazor Server - Play audio not in wwwroot

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app that is reading a .csv file which gives the path to .mp3 files that are recorded dynamically.  I have been able to display the .csv data in a table, but now I would like to offer a Play or Download button for those files.  The files are located on a separate D: data drive (written to by another program).

I discovered that `<source src=@audioPath type="audio/mpeg">` will not work because these files are not in the wwwroot folder.

Would it be best to add a 'app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()' to share that drive directly?

Comment: Blazor doesn't play anything.  A web browser plays a file, which it downloads from those files made public by the server.  Those files are the ones in wwwroot.  If you are using IIS, you can try making a virtual folder to include your storage folder in wwwroot.  Think about the logistics of serving files NOT in wwwroot-- you could accidentally share config files, system files, your credit card info, etc.  You are trying to solve a problem which you should NOT try to solve.  Put your files where they belong.

Comment: Another program is recording the audio and placing only the .mp3 files and database file in this folder.  I can't control where the other program places the audio.   Thank you for your reply though.  I understand more about how the browser is interacting with it.

Comment: Okay, in your case, you need to share the files separately-- all Blazor creates is markup with a path to the file.  Depending on how you are serving your app / files, this should be a trivial thing to do.